# Failed to decode downloaded font: ..../font-family/bariol/bariol_regular-webfont.woff

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Bariol font-family works fine on local wamp server but when i upload files to github then it shows this error in console AND not picking bariol font.

**Failed to decode downloaded font: ..../font-family/bariol/bariol_regular-webfont.woff**

I searched for so long but not get any successful solution for it.

Please help me to out of this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should check is this path correct.
It can work correctly in the first way because you can have it installed on your computer.
Also would be good to see how do you upload fonts in css file.
Also it's weird to see just four dots in a row

Try `../../` instead of `..../`