# "Failed to decode downloaded font" when using gulp-iconfont

Tags: css, fonts, gulp, icon-fonts

I'm using gulp-iconfont v4 to generate fonts from SVGs in a folder.
I'm using a swig template to generate a `.scss` file and include that in my `app.scss`.

When I serve the files I get the following error in the console: `Failed to decode downloaded font` and the icons appear as `[]`.

When I navigate to the file in the url, it downloads fine. What could be causing the browser to not decode them?

I've looked at the following with no resolution:

- [Failed to decode downloaded font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442319/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font)
- [FontAwesome - Failed to decode downloaded font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001842/fontawesome-failed-to-decode-downloaded-font)
- [Failed to decode downloaded font: ..../font-family/bariol/bariol_regular-webfont.woff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694869/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font-font-family-bariol-bariol-regular-webfont)

Sometimes the warning comes from the `.html` page but sometimes it will come from Modernizr or most recently in `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` which isn't actually included anywhere :/

Everything 'works' so I'm not sure what code would be of use.

Here's the response from the file request:

[image]

When I look at the files in the resource panel it just shows the normal A-Z and not any glyphs. Not sure what the expected result is.

EDIT:

I've validated the font using Font Book and all looks well.

[image]

However, the info indicates there are two glyphs (when there should be only one currently) and also doesn't display them at all.

[image]

Comment: "Failed to decode downloaded font" means the font you generated is either corrupt, or is incomplete (missing metrics, necessary tables, naming records, a million possible things). Take the .ttf that gulp generated, and see if it can be unpacked/repacked using [TTX](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools), or even run it through the [OTS](https://github.com/khaledhosny/ots) validator (used by Chrome and Firefox) to see where things break down.

Comment: I validated the font using Font Book and it passed, however it doesn't show any glyphs.

Comment: then fontbook is wrong. Try a TTX conversion and see what's actually there. And perhaps also link to the offending font

Comment: Hi did you come up with a solution in the end?

Comment: Moving back to v1 of the gulp plugin solved the issue. I really can't explain what the real issue is.